# Batch script and special character

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file which is called by *send to* in the context menu of Windows.

```dos
@echo off
:while1
SET _paramini=%1
IF EXIST %_paramini% (
    IF "%2" == "" goto :fin
    SHIFT /1
)
goto :while1
:fin
```

It works except for files with character ";" in their names.

What is the problem in my script?

Comment: what is the meaning of `;;STATEMENT` line?

Comment: It's an error, sorry

Comment: Besides `;`, I'm sure your script fails also with white-spaces, `,` and `=`...

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't really provided us with an indication of what you are wanting to do with existing or not existing files here is a quick example to show you a way that should work:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In (%*) Do If Exist "%%~A" Echo=[%%~A - Exists]
Timeout -1
```

In addition, if you were to change your script thus, it may perform better:

```bat
@echo off
:while1
SET "_paramini=%~1"
IF EXIST "%_paramini%" (
    IF "%~2" == "" goto :fin
    SHIFT /1
)
goto :while1
:fin
```